# Call PHP Function and Return Error or Success Result

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a login function for my php files so I don't repeat the login code on every single page. I'm still working out how to work with functions in PHP. I've created the following function in my functions.php file that I include at the top of every page:

```
function login($hostname, $version, $database, $username, $password) {

    $url = 'https://' . $hostname . '/fmi/data/' . $version . '/databases/' . rawurlencode($database) . '/sessions';
                                 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
                        'Content-Type: '. 'application/json',
                         'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode ($username . ':' . $password)
                     ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    $error = curl_error ($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);  

    $loginResultArray = json_decode ($result, true);

    // Check for Error Message
    $errorCode = $loginResultArray['messages'][0]['code'];
    $errorMessage = $loginResultArray['messages'][0]['message'];

    if ($errorCode !== '0') { 
        // Login Error
        $loginError = 'Login Error: '. $errorMessage. ' (' . $errorCode . ')';
    } else {
        $loginError = '';
        $token = $loginResultArray['response']['token'];

    }
}
```

At the top of each page I'm now adding:

```
require_once 'inc/functions.php';

login($hostname, $version, $database, $username, $password) {
}
```

to call the function. I'd like to include some error checking here so that if the function returned an error or success result I can branch accordingly after calling the function. I'm not sure how to return an error or success result from the function so I can determine if the function was successful or not?

Comment: You could return true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, I think. One option is to throw an exception if the login fails and if there is no error: Return (or maybe store?) the token. Throwing an exception will stop the execution (if you don't catch it where your method is called).

Example:

```php
function login($hostname, $version, $database, $username, $password) {
    // ...

    if ($errorCode !== '0') { 
        // Login Error
        throw new \Exception('Login Error: '. $errorMessage. ' (' . $errorCode . ')');
    } else {
        return $loginResultArray['response']['token'];
    }
}
```

If you don't want to stop the execution in case of an error, you may return a result array and handle the content where your `login()` method was called.

Example:

```php
function login($hostname, $version, $database, $username, $password) {
    // ...

    if ($errorCode !== '0') { 
        // Login Error
        return [
            'error' => 'Login Error: '. $errorMessage. ' (' . $errorCode . ')',
            'token' => null,
        ];
    } else {
        return ['token' => $loginResultArray['response']['token']];
    }
}

// ... In your other file:

require_once 'inc/functions.php';

$loginResult = login($hostname, $version, $database, $username, $password);
if (isset($loginResult['token'])) {
    echo 'You are logged in!';
} else {
    echo $loginResult['error'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> 

```
if ($errorCode !== '0') { 
>         // Login Error
>         $loginError = 'Login Error: '. $errorMessage. ' (' . $errorCode . ')';
>         return false;
>     } else {
>         $loginError = '';
>         $token = $loginResultArray['response']['token'];
>         return true; //here can return $token and check token avail or not 
> 
>     }
```

Comment: Answer without description is not a good answer in SO.